# Set char variable "-" in tcl

Tags: shell, unix, tcl, sh, expect

I'm emulating user input to shell with tcl

```
if {$toOperand == 0} {
 set operand +
} elseif {$toOperand == 1} {
 set operand -
} elseif {$toOperand == 2} {
 set operand *
} elseif {$toOperand == 3} {
set operand :
} elseif {$toOperand == 4} {
 set operand @
} else {set operand #}
```

All of characters are working fine except "-". Here is the error:

```
": must be -i, -h, -s, -null, -0, -raw, -break, or --
   while executing
"send "$operand\r""
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: You might want to consider turning your rather verbose if-elseif-else tango into an operands list, with `toOperand` serving as list index: `set opnds {+ - * : @ #}; set operand [lindex $opnds $toOperand];` ... this assumes that `toOperand` defaults to `end` in some way, to represent your `else` branch.

Comment: @mrcalvin Hey, thanks for suggestion

Comment: A `switch` command would be another alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer:**

Insert a `--` pseudo-option before the operand to announce that no more options follow.

---

**A note about selecting characters:**

There is nothing wrong with your `if` construct, and you should use it if you're happy with it. There are some alternatives that are possibly more compact and easier to read, though.

Since your `toOperand` variable holds values that look like list indices, you could do this:

```
set operands {+ - * : @}
if {0 <= $toOperand && $toOperand < [llength $operands]} {
    set operand [lindex $operands $toOperand]
} else {
    set operand #
}
```

This also works (it is allowed to pass an index that doesn't match any value, it just results in the empty string):

```
set operands {+ - * : @}
set operand [lindex $operands $toOperand]
if {$operand eq {}} {
    set operand #
}
```

If the `toOperand` values weren't straight indices (discontinuous or illegal index values), the above won't work. A similar thing could be done with a `dict` (since `dict get` *doesn't* allow non-matching keys, we need to check if the key matches first):

```
set operandValues {0 + 1 - 2 * 3 : 4 @}
if {[dict exists operandValues $toOperand]} {
    set operand [dict get operandValues $toOperand]
} else {
    set operand #
}
```

In both cases, you are basically free to change the set of operands without changing the code using it.

Another possibility is to use the `switch` command:

```
switch $toOperand {
    0 {
        set operand +
    }
    1 {
        set operand -
    }
    2 {
        set operand *
    }
    3 {
        set operand :
    }
    4 {
        set operand @
    }
    default {
        set operand #
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[&& (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[<= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm)

Comment: The real issue is that `send` takes options and assumes that argument words are options if they start with `-`. Passing `--` before `$operand\r` stops all that stuff.

Comment: @DonalFellows: that was the answer, it was just a little overshadowed by the comment about syntax. Hopefully it's clearer now.